# Merge attributes when using model.set with Backbone Associations

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-associations

My problem is very specific to Backbone Associations (http://dhruvaray.github.io/backbone-associations). I'm wondering if it's possible to merge attributes when setting properties on nested models. Here is a reduction of the issue:

```
// define the Layout model
var Layout = Backbone.AssociatedModel.extend();

// define the User model, with layout as a Related model
var User = Backbone.AssociatedModel.extend({
    relations: [
        {
            type: Backbone.One,
            key: 'layout',
            relatedModel: Layout
        }
    ],
    defaults: {
        layout: {}
    }
});

// create a new user
var user = new User({ user_name: 'pascalpp' });

// set a property on the layout model
user.set('layout.foo', 'bar');
user.get('layout.foo'); // returns 'bar'

// call set on the user directly, passing a JSON structure with no foo property
user.set({ layout: { 'baz': 'bing' } });
user.get('layout.foo'); // foo got wiped, so this returns undefined
```

The real-world scenario I'm facing is that we need to fetch partial data for a user and set that on the user model without obliterating previously set attributes that don't exist in the current fetch. So I'm hoping we can merge when setting attributes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone-associations updates existing nested model if id's of new and existing model match. If id's are undefined or they don't match, then the nested model gets replaced by a new one.

What I do for these singleton nested models is I introduce fake id=0 and then it works like expected.

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulius/pm91xfqn/1/).

Working code:

```
// define the Layout model
var Layout = Backbone.AssociatedModel.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: 0    
    }
});

// define the User model, with layout as a Related model
var User = Backbone.AssociatedModel.extend({
    relations: [
        {
            type: Backbone.One,
            key: 'layout',
            relatedModel: Layout
        }
    ],
    defaults: {
        layout: {}
    }
});

// create a new user
var user = new User({ user_name: 'pascalpp' });

// set a property on the layout model
user.set('layout.foo', 'bar');
user.get('layout.foo'); // returns 'bar'

// call set on the user directly, passing a JSON structure with no foo property
user.set({ layout: { id:0, 'baz': 'bing' } });
user.get('layout.foo'); // foo got wiped, so this returns undefined

alert(user.get('layout.foo'))
```

Comment: Aha! We're already assigning ids to our related models, but we're doing it in the prototype, not in defaults. Will update our code to use defaults so the id gets applied on the instance itself. Thanks!